# Unable to click/select radio button in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying scrape data out of 'https://www.velocityap.com/product/3-0l-v6-supercharged-jaguar-land-rover-aj126-ecu-tuning/' website. For which, set of radio button options need to clicked to reveal price for the car part(price marked in red in picture below) which needs to scraped.

[image: representative image]

Code I've written to achieve that is as follows:

```
options_panel_4 = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.summary.entry-summary > div.mspc-wrapper.mspc-clearfix.mspc-module-accordion.mspc-auto-next.mspc-step-by-step > div > div:nth-child(8) > div > div')
                print('Options under options panel 3 :', len(options_panel_4))

                for option_4 in options_panel_4:
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", option_4)
                    option_4.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div > div.mspc-radio.ui.radio.checkbox > input[type=radio]').click()
```

However, It throws exception as follows:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <div class="mspc-radio ui radio checkbox">...</div> is not clickable at point (890, 14). Other element would receive the click: <div class="infinite-navigation infinite-item-pdlr clearfix infinite-navigation-submenu-indicator ">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=102.0.5005.115)
Stacktrace:
0   chromedriver                        0x00000001024162c9 chromedriver + 5120713
1   chromedriver                        0x00000001023a4e33 chromedriver + 4656691
2   chromedriver                        0x0000000101f94158 chromedriver + 393560
3   chromedriver                        0x0000000101fd0638 chromedriver + 640568
4   chromedriver                        0x0000000101fce1b3 chromedriver + 631219
5   chromedriver                        0x0000000101fcb814 chromedriver + 620564
6   chromedriver                        0x0000000101fca5b2 chromedriver + 615858
7   chromedriver                        0x0000000101fbe249 chromedriver + 565833
8   chromedriver                        0x0000000101fe6482 chromedriver + 730242
9   chromedriver                        0x0000000101fbdb05 chromedriver + 563973
10  chromedriver                        0x0000000101fe658e chromedriver + 730510
11  chromedriver                        0x0000000101ff8f41 chromedriver + 806721
12  chromedriver                        0x0000000101fe6373 chromedriver + 729971
13  chromedriver                        0x0000000101fbc609 chromedriver + 558601
14  chromedriver                        0x0000000101fbd635 chromedriver + 562741
15  chromedriver                        0x00000001023e8b1d chromedriver + 4934429
16  chromedriver                        0x00000001023ed295 chromedriver + 4952725
17  chromedriver                        0x00000001023f23cf chromedriver + 4973519
18  chromedriver                        0x00000001023edcba chromedriver + 4955322
19  chromedriver                        0x00000001023c837c chromedriver + 4801404
20  chromedriver                        0x0000000102407c68 chromedriver + 5061736
21  chromedriver                        0x0000000102407def chromedriver + 5062127
22  chromedriver                        0x000000010241d5e5 chromedriver + 5150181
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff80f3874e1 _pthread_start + 125
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff80f382f6b thread_start + 15
```

Answer (score 1):

What the error code is telling you is that the problem is when you scroll down, the top menu is covering the radio input. So, if it where to click on it, it would't click the radio it'd click the menu.

Also it doesn't let you select the radio itself, you hafe to select a certain div, here's the xpath to that /html/body/div[3]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]

I made a quick try, scrolling manually and selecting the previous radio buttons manually as well, and it selected correctly the last one wich you where having problems with, here's the code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.velocityap.com/product/3-0l-v6-supercharged-jaguar-land-rover-aj126-ecu-tuning/")
options_panel_4 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.summary.entry-summary > div.mspc-wrapper.mspc-clearfix.mspc-module-accordion.mspc-auto-next.mspc-step-by-step > div > div:nth-child(8) > div > div')
time.sleep(15)

                
print('Options under options panel 3 :', len(options_panel_4))

for option_4 in options_panel_4:
    option_4.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]').click()
```

I use xpath because i prefere it, it does not mean you also have to.
I also added a time wait for it to wait for loading and also for me to chose the previous radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

As you want to get datas about all products, so I would get all xpaths of checkboxes, for example '//input[@type="radio" and @value="jaguar-f-type-f-pace-xe-xf-xj"]'. When I will have all xpaths, I will do a script to select all options and I will finish get the text of this xpath '//*[@class="price"]/descendant::span[@class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"]'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).